# Setting up dedicated lock managers in ATG without using CIM

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

I am trying to configure dedicated ATG lock manager servers without running CIM setup. (I need to deploy standalone EARs with dedicated lock servers on servers (we wont be able to run CIM on those servers, I mean to say only ATG installations in there on the servers, I will be creating standalone EARs that shall contain the necessary ATG related dependency modules in the EAR itself(No atg installation on the deploy machine needed)).

I have created a stand alone EAR(Through a system that has atg + CIM setup done). But this I have to do on multiple servers with different set of configuration. We have been told to do so(create EARs) on systems that dont have CIM setup done(all those OPSS and data source configurations wont be there, I need to create the data source and the security files manually(and all other CIM related configurations)).

I installed ATG on a system(system A), I created EARs for my page server(system B) and lock server(The lock server is a dedicated host, system C). I am deploying my pageserver and lockmanager EAR in the respective servers. But as I have not done CIM configuration on system A.

For setting up lock manager I created a server(serverlockmanager on system C) in weblogic that runs at port 9012, and deployed an EAR with DafEar.Admin and DSS modules in it. On my pageserver, I configured client lock manager to point to serverlock manager as per [this](https://atgoasis.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/lock-management-in-atg/) guide.

My page server throws exception for data source and OPSS related security exception. How do I handle them? Please Help me. Also for dedicated lock manager(without running CIM) is the configuration the same as in the guide or am I missing something?.

Comment: Please post your stacktrace.

Comment: Sir I removed the CIM related dependency, by copying home/localConfig folder into the atg/home folder in the deployed EAR. I have now the following scenario, I need a scheduler server that also acts as a lock manager(But I am creating the scheduler server in weblogic only). My scheduler server runs at port 7503. I added the client lock manager properties to point to serverLockManager(at 7503) and I made my scheduler server as(also as) a lockmanager.

Comment: My question is, is this possible(scheduler server and lock manager server running at same port) or should I create another server at say 9010 and deploy lock server EAR on that and point my client lock manager to point to that server instead?

Comment: Having your **Dedicated** ServerLockManager perform other tasks isn't standard practice. Perhaps what you need is another server layer, some sort of util server, that can take care of these tasks. It can also then serve as a preview or staging server for publishing etc.

Comment: Yes sir, But the requirement is like that. My schedular server is also kind of light weight only. That's why I've been told to pack both the EARs togather. My question is can the scheduler and the serverlock manager listen at same port. When CIM create servers with lockmanager, the lockmanager listens at different port.

Comment: Please visit [CRS deployment scripts on GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=atg+crs&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)
May be you can find something useful